# Specific SQL Ordering

Tags: sql, unique, equals

Bit of a newbie to SQL but I'm making my way in pretty well.  My question, however, is of ordering things in a specific way.  Say, for example, that I have the following table:

```
DATE RANGE        NAME    ORDER    COUNT
5/5/14 - 5/6/14   Bob     Food     3
5/5/14 - 5/6/14   Jim     Drink    2
5/4/14 - 5/5/14   Bob     Food     3
```

I would like to order these in a specific way:

```
DATE RANGE        NAME    ORDER    COUNT
5/4/14 - 5/5/14   Bob     Food     3
5/5/14 - 5/6/14   Bob     Food     2
5/5/14 - 5/6/14   Jim     Drink    2
```

To where it is ordered by where name and order are the same, count doesn't necessarily have to be the same, and that is all ordered by date range.  I've tried various permutations of ORDER BY with no luck, but it seems to me like this should overall be a very simple query.  Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: show us the select; but it should be something like `ORDER BY 'Date Range', 'Name', 'Order'` after the where clause  NOTE: ORDER, and name in some cases, is a reserved word so it needs to be wrapped in the appropriate escape characters [] for SQL server ' for ORACLE & Mysql... so what flavor of DB ENGINE?

Comment: So you want it grouped by `NAME` and `ORDER`, and then sorted by `DATE RANGE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/171de/1) for the code. You should `GROUP BY` `NAME`, `ORDER`, `DATE RANGE`, `COUNT`, then `ORDER BY` `DATE RANGE`.

Comment: This way has `DATE RANGE` being the most important. But if it's more important to have them grouped by `ORDER` then remove the `ORDER BY` clause and just use the `GROUP BY`

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ada6/1) is the alternate fiddle. The difference is that if Bob orders Food and drink on 5/4/14-5/5/14, and then food and drink again on 5/5/14-5/6/14, the original fiddle in my answer will sort by date, so 5/4/14 drink, 5/4/14 food, then 5/5/14 drink, then 5/5/14 food. This fiddle would group by order over date, so it would be 5/4/14 drink, then 5/5/14 drink, then 5/4/14 food, then 5/5/14 food. I'm not 100% sure which way you preferred so there is both to choose from.